# delete property with sequential index in object

Tags: javascript, lodash

i have an object like below:

```
item = {
  0: 'A',
  1: 'B',
  2: 'C',
  3: 'D'
}
```

For e.g., if i would like to delete '1' from the item object and after it was deleted, '2' and '3' should auto minus 1 and become object below:

```
item = {
  0: 'A',
  1: 'C',
  2: 'D'
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this with object beside using array?

Comment: Possible, yes, to some extent, have you tried anything yourself yet? Please post what you've tried. But why not use an array?

Comment: Use an array , (it's also  an object) .... for deleting use `Array#splice` method

Comment: There's nothing that will do this automatically for an object, you have to write the code yourself. If you use an array, you can use `.splice()` to do it.

Comment: @FireHand I have dded another answer, please check if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Omit the key you don't want, convert to array using `Object.values()`, and then convert back to object by spreading to an empty object:

```js
const item = {
  0: 'A',
  1: 'B',
  2: 'C',
  3: 'D'
}

const result = { ...Object.values(_.omit(item, 1)) }

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Or you can create a function that uses rest params:

```js
const fn = (key, { [key]: _, ...rest }) => ({ ...Object.values(rest) })

const item = {
  0: 'A',
  1: 'B',
  2: 'C',
  3: 'D'
}

const result = fn(1, item)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a delete statement

```
delete item["1"];
```

Comment: I've used the delete statement many times, it works well. Just put the property name in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array for removing and for re-indexing purpose.

```js
let item = {
  0: 'A',
  1: 'B',
  2: 'C',
  3: 'D'
};

// get values as an array
let arr = Object.values(item);

// remove element at index 1
arr.splice(1, 1);

// extract array to an object
item = {
  ...arr
};

console.log(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another solution in case you don't want to rely in third party plugins. Lodash is quite a heavy library as well.

```
var deleteObj = ({data, index}) => {
    var objSize = Object.keys(data).length
    if (index > objSize -1) return data
    var count = index;
    delete data[count];
    count = count+1;
   while (count < objSize){
      data[count-1] = data[count];
      count = count+1;
  }
  delete data[count-1];
  return data;
}

deleteObj({data: {0: "A", 1: "B", 2: "C", 3: "D", 4: "E", 5: "F"}, index: 0});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or else you can use [lodash's filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#filter) directly on object (actually you can) to remove unnecessery items and then produce an array in one step, and then just use object spread operator to build back the resultant object.

Example:

```js
let o = {"0":"A","1":"B","2":"C","3":"D"},
    res = {..._.filter(o, (v, k) => k!=1)};
    
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```